# a way to check validity of HTML5 forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, dom

Is it possible to check if an input element of an html5 form is valid based on the pattern I set for it? I know the psuedo class stuff.. but i'm hoping something like:
`document.getElementById('petitionName').valid`
can return `true` or `false`..

I really hope I don't need to create javascript to re-verify this stuff.

Answer (score 122):

there are two ways to check the validity.

1. `inputElement.checkValidity()` returns `true` or `false`
2. `inputElement.validity` returns the validity-state object. `inputElement.validity.valid` returns `true/false`

Instead of using keyup, you can also use the 'input' event. All browser, which have implemented the constraint validation API, have also implemented the input-event.

If you are using option 1 above, Opera has a bug here and will show its validation hint. So you should use 2.

I have created a html5 forms library, which implements all unknown features to incapable browsers + fixes issues in HTML5 browsers. So everything works like defined in the spec, but it's built on top of jQuery.
 (http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html).

Comment: Hmm, I just wanted a checkValidity plugin that was backwards compatible. Seems your library has too many built in functions and the docs are hard to read.

Comment: I think the `change` event is better suited for validity check.

Comment: is there a way to use flags (e.g. `i`) in the HTML pattern?

Comment: CheckValidity browser support looks good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`pattern` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute).

It will validate it client side, so no need to validate it again client side.

[image: Example]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tRqvp/).

**But**, make sure you do it again server side.

Also note, because browser compatibility is quite poor right now, JavaScript is the norm for validating client side.

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to avoid using any frameworks, and my pattern attribute is already set. I was hoping I can access the input element via DOM and determine if the element is value or not.

Comment: yep, I know :) I have the same setup already made and I want to avoid using any JQuery form validator. I know I can set patterns or types that validate for me. And I've already done that. But I want to call functions once the input element is valid. I'm listening to 'onKeyUp' events on the elements, but no way to verify that they are in fact valid. I have CSS that communicates the element validity but that isn't enough.

Comment: @Henry You could loop through the `input` elements, extracting their `pattern` attribute and testing the resulting regex.

Comment: yeah - thats exactly what I want to avoid :)  I did figure it out though:                            function checkValid(){    document.getElementById('email').validity.valid;
    };                                       that works in Chrome and iOS 4.3 :) thanks Alex!

Comment: @Henry Ah yeah, I saw that property there and was about to mention it :)

Comment: is HTML pattern validation sufficient for client-side validation nowadays?

Answer (score 6):

To complement, you can check each element was invalid and, for example, set a focus in the first invalid element, by this code:

```
var Form = document.getElementById('FormID');
if (Form.checkValidity() == false) {
    var list = Form.querySelectorAll(':invalid');
    for (var item of list) {
        item.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to set focus on the last element. I mean, the first then the 2nd, then the Nth, then the last. I guess you're right, it'll set it on the first element -- even keep focus on the first element if the first is also the last. You could use `querySelector` to avoid all that though.

Answer (score 0):

`inputElement.checkValidity()` returns boolean, but if you are working on a form-heavy page I would consider using some package like [forms.js](https://github.com/form-js/forms.js) to handle client-side validation.

You can find more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35411369)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the validity of an input element in an HTML5 form using the `checkValidity()` method. This method is available on the `HTMLInputElement` interface and returns a Boolean value indicating whether the input satisfies its validation constraints.

```
<form>
  <label for="petitionName">Petition Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="petitionName" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="checkValidity()">Check Validity</button>
</form>

<script>
function checkValidity() {
  var petitionNameInput = document.getElementById('petitionName');
  var isValid = petitionNameInput.checkValidity();

  if (isValid) {
    alert('Input is valid!');
  } else {
    alert('Input is not valid!');
  }
}
</script>
```

You can find more information here:https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145t