# how to check html5 form validity with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

HTML:

```
<form id="myform"  method="post">
    <input name="email"  type="email" required=""/>
    <input name="fname" type="text" required="" />
    <input name="zip" type="text" />
    <input  type="button" value="button" />
</form>
```

Here I want to just check email by applying javascript function for **html5** can we do that?

**Edit**
It has been unclear/misunderstood before. My question is do we have boolean valid check like `form.email.valid()` so that we can do check for email only with using javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846382/a-way-to-check-validity-of-html5-forms

Answer (score 2):

You should change your button input. A HTML5 submit button needs to look like the following:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Also, giving your e-mail a placeholder would be nice:

```
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="me@example.com" required=""/>
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFNdV/2/).

Comment: I need to call by not submitting the form or I may need to check the validity of just email .

Comment: @vusan Have you tried the jsFiddle? it already validates whether it's an e-mail or not

Comment: ok now can we use like `$('#form')[0].checkValidity()` with pure javascript.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688122/html5-form-validation-void-form-action-and-execute-jquery-when-all-html5-form-e) has a accepted answer, to the "same" question, just submit and preventDefaults.

Comment: @vusan Yep! check out the link that winner_joiner posted for that