# See if CSS :invalid selector is currently active in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

I am working on a personal project and am trying to do some error validation on a form using HTML5 and JavaScript.

My HTML code:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>BPMeasure</h1>
    </header>
    <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = main();">
        Track A: <input name="input_a" id="input_a" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" value="0"><br/>
        Track B: <input name="input_b" id="input_b" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" value="0"><br/>
        <br />
        Output: <output name="o" for="a b"></output>
    </form>
</body>
```

My JavaScript Code:

```
function calculate(track_a, track_b) {
    if(track_a > track_b) {
        return ((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100;
    } else if(track_a < track_b) {
        return ((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100;
    } else {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

function main() {
    var track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
    var track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;

    var message = isTrackValid(track_a, track_b);
    if(message !== "") {
        return message;
    } else {
        return calculate(track_a, track_b);
    }
}
```

Right now, `isValid()` is a placeholder. I want it so when someone enters an invalid number into `track_a` or `track_b` they get an error message in the output (the `return message` portion). An invalid number is specifically something like `3+`, `3++`, `3.-4`, `5..5`, etc.

To figure out if the input was invalid I use this css code:

```
form input[type=number]:invalid {
    background-color: #ff8878;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to use this because if someone enters an invalid number (like the examples above), it will always return `NaN`. This means that if the user hasn't even typed anything we have the value `NaN`, which means it continually displays an error message. This is why I have the `invalid` css code above.

My question is, is there a way in JavaScript to detect if the `input` currently has the attribute `invalid`, and if so can I return an error message until they either fix the error or clear the input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a way to check validity of HTML5 forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846382/a-way-to-check-validity-of-html5-forms)

Answer (score 1):

As said in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846382/a-way-to-check-validity-of-html5-forms),

1. `inputElement.checkValidity()` returns true or false
2. `inputElement.validity` returns the validity-state object. `inputElement.validity.valid` returns true/false

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inputs' **[checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Methods)** method.  It's [**supported**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Browser_compatibility) by all modern browsers and IE10+.

From MDN:

> Returns false if the element is a candidate for constraint validation,
>   and it does not satisfy its constraints. In this case, it also fires
>   an invalid event at the element. It returns true if the element is not
>   a candidate for constraint validation, or if it satisfies its
>   constraints.

```js
function isValid(input_a, input_b) {
  if(!input_a.checkValidity() || !input_b.checkValidity()) {
    return 'error';
  }
  return '';
} //isValid

function calculate(track_a, track_b) {
  if (track_a > track_b) {
    return ((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100;
  } else if (track_a < track_b) {
    return ((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100;
  } else {
    return 0.0;
  }
}

function main() {
  var track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
  var track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;

  var message = isValid(input_a, input_b);
  if (message !== "") {
    return message;
  } else {
    return calculate(track_a, track_b);
  }
}
```

```css
form input[type=number]:invalid {
  background-color: #ff8878;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = main();">
  Track A:
  <input name="input_a" id="input_a" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" value="0">
  <br/>Track B:
  <input name="input_b" id="input_b" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" value="0">
  <br/>
  <br />Output:
  <output name="o" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```