# How to validate email?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate an email address to make sure its correct. e.g Includes "@" symbol. What do I add to my existing code?

Here is my code for the email address with other inputs in the form:

```js
$(".next").click(function(){

//text inputs
  if(!document.getElementById('fullname').value) {
    alert('Full Name is required');
    return false;
  }

  else if(!document.getElementById('email').value) {
    alert('Email is required');
    return false;
  }

  else if(!document.getElementById('phone').value) {
    alert('Phone Number is required');
    return false;
  }

  else if(!document.getElementById('age').value) {
    alert('Age is required');
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: you can just simply use `HTML5 form validity` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605773/html5-email-validation

Comment: I need to code in terms of Javascript, my code will not allow your answer. How can I test for "@" symbol in Java

Comment: What do you mean by testing for "@" symbol in java ? Can you be specific please

Comment: You can check `HTML5 form validity` by `inputElement.checkValidity()` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846382/a-way-to-check-validity-of-html5-forms

Comment: If the input does not have an "@" then the code will return an alert. For example: hellogmail.com vs hello@gmail.com (hello@gmail.com will work, while hellogmail.com will not)

Answer (score 1):

On your email input you can especify the type like this:

```
<input type="email" id="emailTest">
```

So on the form submit the Browser automaticaly validate the input

Or you can use a JavaScript Function Regex like this:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
```

}

Comment: I need to code in terms of Javascript, my code will not allow your answer. How can I test for "@" symbol in Java

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two different languages. I also suggest using the HTML solution, it's more semantically correct and will check for proper email address formatting.

Comment: Fixed to validate with JavaScript!