# How to validate textbox to a specified pattern

Tags: javascript

I have below code that is working fine, but I want to validate textbox TBMonday to force users to enter in the specified pattern. How can I do this with Javascript (Please I don't want to use input type='time')

```
    <input type="text" id="TBMonday" size="7" placeholder="hh:mm-hh:mm" pattern="(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1- 
     9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])-(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0- 
     9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])" onKeyUp="TBMondayEl();">

    <input type="text" id="TBMonday2" size="7">

    <script>
     function TBMondayEl() 
     {
       document.getElementById('TBMonday2').value = document.getElementById('TBMonday').value;
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a way to check validity of HTML5 forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846382/a-way-to-check-validity-of-html5-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally write my code and it work for me.

```
    <input type="text" id="TBMonday" size="7" placeholder="hh:mm-hh:mm" required 
     onblur="validateMon();" onKeyUp="TBMondayEl();">

    <input type="text" id="TBMonday2" size="7">


    <script>
     function validateMon(){
     var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('TBMonday').value;

     var phoneRGEX = /^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5] 
     [0-9]$/;

     var phoneResult = phoneRGEX.test(phoneNumber);

      if(phoneResult == false)
      {
       document.getElementById('TBMonday').value = '';
       document.getElementById('TBMonday2').value = '';
       alert('Please enter TimeBelt in "HH:MM-HH:MM" format');
       return false;
        }

        return true;
        }




     <script>
      function TBMondayEl() 
        {
         document.getElementById('TBMonday2').value 
         document.getElementById('TBMonday').value;
         }
     </script>
```